# Best MySQL configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql

I have a DirectAdmin/CentOS 7.0 VM with 8 GB RAM.

I ran the MySQLTuner script, and followed the recommendations that they gave, but it's still recommending increases.

My current config in my my.cnf file is:

```
[mysqld]

bind-address = 127.0.0.1
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
innodb_file_per_table

key_buffer = 2G  
max_allowed_packet = 150M
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 256M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
thread_cache_size = 128
max_connections = 100 
wait_timeout = 30 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
max_heap_table_size = 32M
table_open_cache = 1024
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 32M
```

When I run the script, this is what I get:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.6.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.41-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 122M (Tables: 6)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1010M (Tables: 396)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 53

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[!!] User '@localhost' is an anonymous account.
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list !

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1m 7s (2K q [30.612 qps], 21 conn, TX: 22M, RX: 5M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 6.3G global + 42.3M per thread (100 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 6.4G (83.50% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 10.4G (136.46% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (2/100)
[!!] Aborted connections: 4.76%  (1/21)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 39.1% (1K cached / 3K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 152 sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 2
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 18% (32 on disk / 173 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 90% (2 created / 21 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 123% (130 open / 105 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (25/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)

-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (390M used / 2B cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.0G/80.3M
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 66.7% (6 cached / 2 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/1010.9M
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 5.00% (13095 used/ 262143 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 96.99% (352202 hits/ 363150 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 32 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Remove Anonymous User accounts - there are 1 Anonymous accounts.
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 32.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=4)
```

How should I edit my my.cnf file to achieve the best settings?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the setting that I have used in the past

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

#innodb settings
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1800
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G 

#other vars
net_read_timeout=120
skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
table_cache=2048
thread_cache_size=16
back_log=100
max_connect_errors=10000
open-files-limit=20000
interactive_timeout=3600
wait_timeout=1800
max_connections=200
key_buffer_size=1G
connect_timeout=120

#skip-name-resolve
max_allowed_packet=16M
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M
query_cache_size=256M
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
join_buffer_size=3M
```

Of course some of the settings you will need to adjust depending on the amount of memory you have available to MySQL. I would also recommend Percona as a drop in replacement.

Comment: Thanks! What were your server specs? I mean, how many CPU, RAM etc?

Comment: This server had dual quad core and 48gb ram. You can adjust yours accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot! But in that case I should only change the innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G to innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G. Because I run a 8GB ram, 4 quad core server. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: I tried that code inside my my.cnf file, but that does break my entire Magento store. Do I need to edit anything else?

Comment: Check you data directory

Comment: I also tried to remove the data directory, because I do not have defined it currently, but that also breaks down the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: @brentwpeterson his and your configs are way off of a target. mysql configuration is not what you can share, but instead you must have some basic config to start off.

Answer (score 2):

this is very simple - just read mysqltuner, the most important lines:

> [--] Total buffers: 6.3G global + **42.3M** per thread (100 max threads)
>   [OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 6.4G (83.50% of installed RAM)
>  [!!]
>   Maximum possible memory usage: **10.4G** (136.46% of installed RAM)

it tells you that buffers are too big and total memory will be allocated incorrectly.

so you have to lower them, and start at least with:

```
key_buffer = 128M
join_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 256M

interactive_timeout = 7200
wait_timeout = 7200
net_read_timeout = 120
net_write_timeout = 300
```